# Testing string and integer arrays against user input

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, user-input

I have created arrays for strings and integers I want to use in my program and I want to use them instead of using

```
(name.equals "barry"||"matty"
```

for example.

I want to know how to write the if statement to check the user input against the strings in the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        // array containing usernames 
        String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; 

        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        name = kb.nextLine();
        if (name.equals("barry ")|| name.equals("matty" ) || name.equals("olly")||name.equals("joey"))
            System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");

        Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
        int floor;

        int [] floor = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        System.out.println("What floor do you want to go to ");
        floor = f.nextInt();

        if (floor >7)
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
        else if (floor <= 7)
            System.out.println("Entry valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're just looking for `List.contains` - but that requires a `List` rather than an array, of course. There are two obvious options here.

Firstly, you could use a `List<String>` to start with:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("barry");
names.add("matty");
names.add("olly");
names.add("joey");
...
if (names.contains(name))
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Arrays.asList` to create a view:

```
String[] names = {"barry", "matty", "olly", "joey"}; 
List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(names);
...
if (namesList.contains(name))
{
}
```

As a third option, if you put make your names array sorted (either by hand or by calling `Arrays.sort`) you could use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object%3aA-java.lang.Object-) to try to find the name entered by the user:

```
String[] names = {"barry", "matty", "olly", "joey"}; 
Arrays.sort(names);
...
if (Arrays.binarySearch(names, name) >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your array instead:

```
String name = kb.nextLine();
if(contains(name)) {
    System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
}


public boolean contains(String name) {
    String [] names = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; 
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if(names[i].equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
        }
    }
```

Or you can use [`List.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), in this case you have to add your names inside `List` instead of regular array.

For Example:

```
String[] names = {"barry", "matty", "olly", "joey"}; 
List<String> namesList= Arrays.asList(names);

if (namesList.contains(name)) {
    System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are very low-level structures that don't provide any method. You'd better use collections instead, which have a `contains()` method:

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}));

if (names.contains(name)) {
    ...
}
```

Since you don't seem to care about the order of the names, but only want to test if the collection contains a name or not, a HashSet is the best data structure: `HashSet.contains()` runs in constant time (O(1)), whereas `List.contains()`, for example, is O(n).

Read the [collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Answer (score 1):

Using ArrayList and List instead of Array of Strings:

```
List<String>names = new ArrayList<String>(names); 
name = kb.nextLine();
if(names.indexOf(name)>-1)System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
```

This because of the indexof in List returns -1 if not found or the index of the founded element, starting with 0.

I think that also

```
if(names.contains(name))System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
```

works

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
get input
for int i = 0, i < array size i++
if input.equals(array[i]) then do stuff
```

If you switch to an `arraylist`, you can do `if(array.contains(input))`